# Java in python3-onbuild docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to run a java programm inside the [python3-onbuild](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) image (it is based on debian jessie)
.
I extended the dockerfile with the installation of java, but if i try to print out the version it results in

> System error: exec: "java": executable file not found in $PATH

I created a [repository](https://github.com/svenhornberg/stack_pyjava) with my code.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
ONBUILD RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "openjdk-7-jre"]

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ONBUILD ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/default
ONBUILD ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

CMD ["java", "-version"]
```

Any idea whats wrong and how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding `ONBUILD`. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild):

> The ONBUILD instruction adds to the image a trigger instruction to be
>   executed at a later time, when the image is used as the base for
>   another build. The trigger will be executed in the context of the
>   downstream build, as if it had been inserted immediately after the
>   FROM instruction in the downstream Dockerfile.

So, when `docker build` encounters the `FROM` instruction in your `Dockerfile`, it will execute on `ONBUILD` instructions from the python image. In your `Dockerfile`, the `ONBUILD` instructions are never executed, as they would only be triggered if the image is referenced from another `Dockerfile`.

I think you just meant to use `RUN` instead of `ONBUILD`, but I'm not sure why you are trying to use `ONBUILD` at all.